# std::ios::binary or std::ifstream::binary and similar?

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

While searching for file reading examples in C++, I notice that many examples use

- `std::ios::binary` vs `std::ifstream::binary`
- `std::ios::beg` vs `your_file_stream.beg`
- `std::ios::end` vs `your_file_stream.end`

Are there any differences in these examples, and if not, why are they both included in the STL?

Comment: While a good question, i think this is primarily opinion based. They are the same thing, just different ways to reference them.

Comment: My feeling is the first part is opinion based, but the second one isn't.

Comment: I think you may have a typo in your question. Are you really asking if `std::ios::beg` is the same as `std::ios::end`? Are you really asking if the beginning of something is the same as the end of something?

Comment: The guy who edited my question didn't edit it well, I'll correct ;)

Comment: Yeah, that was a bad edit. Not just bad formatting, but he also fundamentally changed your question in the final paragraph.

Comment: @DagobertoPires - I'm that guy, sorry. I didn't look at the examples well enough I'm afraid. However, the original question was way too opinion-based.

Answer (score 4):

`std::ios::binary` vs. `std::ifstream::binary` is largely down to personal choice, but I always use the more "fundamental" definition insofar that it's further up the inheritance tree if you get my meaning. Hence `std::ios::binary` is my choice.

As for `std::ios::beg` and `your_file_stream.beg`, I'd plump for the former: it's pointless and obfuscating to reach a `static` member via an instance.

Answer (score 2):

They ARE the same, since `ifstream` inherit from `ios`...

There is no "idiom" there. Just opinions.

My personal one is that you shold protect you code in a way a change in the library it uses will retain you code consistency.

So `your_file_stream.end` is always coherent to `your_file_stream` whatever it is and however it is composed in present and future versions. And even if it happens to be different respect to other stream types, will always work.

If you don't have an instance, `std::ifstream::binary` is always coherent with `ifstream`, however it will be composed now and in the future. And will word even if it will be different from other types.

If you're writing a polymorphic runtime-function taking `std::ios&`, than `std::ios::binary` is fine.

However it will be unlikely those things will ever be changed, so ... it does not really matters.